# GARCH data modeling

Tags: econometrics, finance, time-series

I am analyzing three time series returns for stocks, bonds and real estate, and have done prelimanary tests including Engle's ARCH test which came back as not rejecting the null hypothesis. IF there are no ARCH effects can I still use GARCH modeling?